# Manual entries missing in MinGW-MSYS

Tags: windows, mingw, msys, manpage

I installed MinGW with MSYS on my Windows 8.1 computer so I can work in the same conditions at school (we work on Debian) and at home for compiling C programs with GCC, using makefile and the manual.

I installed the manual with this command : `mingw-get install msys-man`

But when I type this : `man 2 read`, I get this message :

> No entry for read in section 2 of the manual

Is something missing to my installation ?

**EDIT :** It seems that there is not a single entry in my man, when I type `man chmod`, I still get the "No manual entry for chmod" message.